# Push into arrays with setState - React Native

Tags: react-native, api, push, setstate, promise.all

i'm new to React Native and i was working on a project using api from different url's. When i use the fetch to the url's, i want so set my state with setState but when i try it, the console.warn shows my arrays empy. What is the problem in my code? I appreciate any feedback :)

```
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {

      location: [],
      current: [],
      condition: [],
      cities: ["london", "paris", "hongkong", "buenos_aires"]
    
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    let fetches = []
    this.state.cities.forEach(
      city => {
        let resp = fetch('http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=10eb2b8701194b128b2122427211005&q=' + city + '&aqi=no').then(res => res.json());
        fetches.push(resp)
      }
    )


    Promise.all(fetches).then(jsonList => {

      jsonList.forEach(
        json => {
          this.setState(state => {
            const location = state.location.concat(json.location)
            const current = state.current.concat(json.current)
            const condition = state.condition.concat(json.condition)

            return {
              location,
              current,
              condition,
            }
          })


        })
    }).catch(function (error) {

      console.error(error)
    })
    console.warn(this.state)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` does not update the state immediately -- it gets updated on the next render. Assuming you're actually getting data back from your API, your `console.warn` is showing the state from the current render.

You can use the callback function (second argument of `setState`) to see the value after it's been set.

You can also make all of the updates in one shot by using array spreading.

```
Promise.all(fetches).then(jsonList => {
  this.setState(state => {
     return {
       location: [...state.location, ...jsonList.map(i => i.location)],
       current: [...current, ...jsonList.map(i => i.current)],
       condition: [...state.condition, ...jsonList.map(i => i.condition)],
     }
  },() => {
     console.log(this.state);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was exactly as you say. Once i rendered it, everything i set on my state was there! And tnx for the callbackfunction and array spreading tips, they came very handy.

Comment: Great -- you can mark the answer as correct/accepted with the green checkmark and if you thought it was helpful, you can upvote with the arrow as well.

Comment: My bad, im new to stackoverflow ;)